# react custom hook state is not updating when re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm having an issue when repopulating form for edit using react hooks.

**Parent Component : Edit.js**

```
const EditData = (props) => {
    const { Id } = props.match.params;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    // calling redux action to get the data
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getDataById(Id));
    }, [Id]);
    const data = useSelector((state) => state.data);
    const initialState = {
      Id: data.cardId || '',
      Number: data.Number || '',
      Date: data.Date,
    };
    //calling custom hook
    const { handleChange, handleSubmit, values,errors } = useForm(
        initialState,// passing initial state to custom hook
        validateOnSubmit,
        submit
    );
    // used to submit the data
    function submit() {
      dispatch(updateCard(values));
    }
    return (<DateForm
            handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            values={values}
            />);
  };
```

**Custom hook: useform.js**

```
  const useForm = (initialState, validateOnSubmit, callback) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
    const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
      const { name, value } = event.target;
      setValues({
        ...values,
        [name]: value
      });
    };
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setErrors(validateOnSubmit(values));
      setIsSubmitting(true);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) {
        callback();
      }
    }, [errors]);

    return {
      handleChange,
      handleSubmit,
      values,
      errors
    };
  };
```

when the API call get finished the react re-render the custom but the local state of the hook is not updating.

```
const useForm = (initialState, validateOnSubmit, callback) => {
      console.log(initialState);
```

> on second render, here i can receive data from the API

```
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);
```

> but **values** is not getting updated, **values** is still holding the state from the initial render

I cannot figure out why this is. I'm just started to use react hooks, please help me.

Comment: Are you asking why `initialState` is updated but the `values` arent?

Comment: I assume getDataById is imported?

Comment: Although not strictly related to this, it's advised not to capitalize property names. So, is 'Id' correct from props.match.params or should it be 'id'?

Comment: @DennisVash yes, the `initialState` variable is updated when the api call get completed,im passing that `initialState` variable to   `const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);` , so it should update the `values` variable right?. but its not !

Comment: @rrd yes. its a redux action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As OP stated in a comment:

> the initialState variable is updated when the API call get completed,I'm passing that initialState variable to const [values, setValues] = `useState(initialState);` , so it should update the values variable right?. but it's not!

It is should update the state, the initial state is assigned once until the component unmounts.

See [`useState` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), it stated in [lazy initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

> The `initialState` argument is the state used during the initial render. **In subsequent renders, it is disregarded.**